# Needing to pass array values into an ms-access query

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a form in Access 2010 where I have check boxes of insurance carriers.  Once the user clicks the "next" button my vba is looking to see what is checked and passing those into an array that does a preserve redim to keep it only as large as the number of carriers that were selected.  I then do a join on my array so that it will say (for example when put out to a message box) "AIG, Arch, Travelers, Zurich"

I want to take this array (called Carriers) and pass it into a query as the criteria for that query.  How would I pass this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass an array as a parameter to a query, but you can perform the `VBA.Join` on the array in VBA, and then pass the delimited string to the query.